# How to get data from Google to Arduino

Tags: arduino

First off, I'm a complete noob when it comes to Arduino. I'm trying to build this project that will tell me when the next Chelsea game is going to happen in the English Premier League. This will include an LCD display that is connected to my Arduino Uno R3 along with a WiFly shield that will connect wirelessly to Google and get the appropriate information.

Once my Arduino finds out when the next Chelsea game is, it will output a countdown on the LCD to the next game. Additional functionality will include which team Chelsea is going to face off against.

My primary question here is: How can I connect to Google via my WiFly shield, search for the next Chelsea game and transport that data to my Arduino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check at football - related APIs and projects. This is a good place to get started. [LINK](http://www.jokecamp.com/blog/guide-to-football-and-soccer-data-and-apis/#fdata)

I do not think it is doable with google.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check these out.